# Can't see symbolicated crash report on fabric

Tags: ios, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have integrated `fabrics` into my project. And its bit code enabled. Now in dashboard I can see many issues. But they are not symbolicated. Hence I uploaded the `dsym` manually after downloading it from iTunes connect. It has uploaded, but it is still showing that we are still processing.

[image]

Now I see that last version's `UUID` has cut off, but I can't see any result.

Comment: Usually it would take some time to process the DSYM's. After that you are good to view the crash report.

Answer (score 2):

Todd from Fabric here - After you upload the dSYMs and they shown as crossed out in the dashboard they enter a queue for reprocessing. That can take any where from near instantly to a couple hours depending on the status of our queue. If reprocessing is unsuccessful we don't show the crashes on your dashboard, if it is successful they appear in your dashboard. Either way, once new crashes occur they will appear in your dashboard or you will get a new missing dSYM warning related to a different UUID. Thanks!

Comment: "If reprocessing is unsuccessful we don't show the crashes on your dashboard" - What can cause it to be unsuccessful?  If it's unsuccessful is the crash lost forever?